# How to display console log value on submit on next page in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I get console log output from  onSubmit() {
console.log(`Tack för bokningen ${this.name}`);
} to be displayed in bokningscheck.component.html instead of skidetails.component.html

skidetails.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-skiedetails',
      templateUrl: './skiedetails.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./skiedetails.component.scss']
    })
    export class SkiedetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    
      @Input()
      name?: string;
    
      constructor() {}
      
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
    
      onSubmit() {
        console.log(`Tack för bokningen ${this.name}`);
      }
    }
```

skiedetails.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name">
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/check', skie.id]">Bekräfta</button>
              </form>
```

bokningscheck.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bokningscheck',
  templateUrl: './bokningscheck.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bokningscheck.component.scss']
})
export class BokningscheckComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In this file I want the value from skidetail.component.ts
when you press the submit button in skidetail.component.html to be displayed in the console

bokningscheck.html

```
 <p>bokningscheck works!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below.

bokningscheck.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bokningscheck',
  template: ``,
  styles: [],
})
export class BokningscheckComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'check/:id',
    component: BokningscheckComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SkiedetailsComponent,
    BokningscheckComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lawaxf)

Let me know if you have any doubt.